# Launching web page with selenium 3

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to run chrome with selenium 3 with this code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","PathToJars/chromedriver.exe");

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("start-maximized");
options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
options.addArguments("--test-type");
options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

driver.get("http://seleniumhq.org/");
driver.quit();
```

but the web page doesn't display and I got this log message:

> Starting ChromeDriver (v2.9.248315) on port 28614
>   nov. 28, 2018 3:20:33 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
>   INFOS: Detected dialect: OSS
>   Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":{"frameId":"E07F9F754F55BF599E5A758E1DB3F9F3","isDefault":true,"type":"default"},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}
>     (Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.110)
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
>   Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
>   System info: host: 'DESKTOP-6OA6NK5', ip: '192.168.43.198', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_191'
>   Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
>   Capabilities {acceptSslCerts: true, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {userDataDir: "removed intentially"...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, handlesAlerts: true, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, nativeEvents: true, platform: XP, platformName: XP, rotatable: false, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, version: 70.0.3538.110, webStorageEnabled: true}

[image]

Comment: Can you try it with http**s**://seleniumhq.org/ instead? And make sure you can access the website normally.

Comment: Hello @natn2323 I tried but still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Try With this, Hope it helps

Add The Binary Path of your browser  in your code.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
        options.setBinary(new File("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"));
        options.addArguments("start-maximized");
        options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
        options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "F:\\New folder\\chromedriver.exe");

        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: Hello @koushick I tried but still the same problem

Comment: @narcisse is your error is same? or something new is coming?

Comment: I got the same error.. nothing has changed

Comment: Have thrown Webdriver Exception in your code? @narcisse